# Statistic collection tool for C#?

Tags: c#, statistics, usage-statistics

Is there a good tool to collect statistics from within C# a application. 
Basically we want to save successful method calls, what parameter values were passed in, the IP addresses (for web applications), failed attempts to retrieve data. More or less anything.
We need then to be able to query the database containing the data to generate statistic charts and diagrams.

Right now we are doing it ourselves with 5 tables. The main table contains the request, then we have a parameter table, data table, application table (to track different applications) and then a method table. We also expose a webservice for other projects (like php and flash). They send their data to the webservice and that's then stored in the main statistics database.

We would like to know if there is such a tool on that market that can do this and perhaps more? (Does not have to be open source or free to use)

Answer (score 4):

A good tool for this would be gibraltar http://www.gibraltarsoftware.com/.  Not only is the software very good but the people behind it are very friendly and helpful.

Comment: Thanks Kevin for the vote of confidence in us! We have some great options for this in the box plus ways to go deeper if you want.  Just download the trial and reach out to us via live chat or support for more help on your specific scenario!